# Google Calendar Not Displaying Co-workers Calendar Events Correctly

Tags: google-chrome, events, time, google-calendar-api

I have a co-worker who has suddenly developed a problem with her Google Calendar. It seems that it has pushed her time slots up one, yet her timezone is correct, and we're in Saskatchewan, where we don't change our clocks!

Ex: Her meeting that she was supposed to have at noon, shows up in the 11am time slot.

The is a recent discovery. Is there a possibility that she did something, and everything shifted? It's not just for one day either, it's for all the events she has. She has it synced with her Blackberry, if that helps at all.

Any ideas, hints, etc are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that synchronization with the Blackberry may be to blame. For instance if it was created/synched with a BB device it may have put an incorrect time zone on the calendar event.

One way to check would be to go to Google Calendar and see what time zone is set for the event (It should be GMT - 6 Regina).